# Simson's Rule but Intervals Aren't the Same

Tags: calculus, approximation, simpsons-rule

I'm currently working on some homework, and ran into a question that has stumped me. We're working on Simpson's rule, which is easy enough, but then I got to a problem where the intervals aren't the same.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 Time(seconds)& 1.2& 1.7& 2.3& 3.0& 3.9& 4.8& 5.9& 7.1& 8.5\\ \hline
 Velocity(mph)& 30& 40& 50& 60& 70& 80& 90& 100& 110\\ \hline
\end{array}

It also gives me the information $60mph = 88 ft/sec$

I'm supposed to be using Simpson's rule to estimate the distance traveled by the car from time $t = 1.2 seconds$ and $t = 8.5 seconds$, but the time intervals aren't the same. What do I need to do to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use integration by parts

$$s=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}vdt=\!\!\!\!\!\left.\phantom{\frac{1}{2}}vt\,\right|_{t_1}^{t_2}-\int_{v_1}^{v_2}tdv.$$

Since your $v$ is equally spaced, you can do Simpson's integral. [Simpson's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule) is more accurate for equally spaced intervals because the third-order Taylor term is canceled as "free lunch".

Or one can use the formula

$$\int_a^bf(t)dg(t)\approx\begin{bmatrix}f(a),\;f(\frac{a+b}{2}),\;f(b)\end{bmatrix}\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
\displaystyle-\frac{1}{2} & \displaystyle\frac{2}{3} & \displaystyle-\frac{1}{6}\\\displaystyle-\frac{2}{3} & 0\, & \displaystyle\frac{2}{3}\\
\displaystyle\frac{1}{6} & \displaystyle-\frac{2}{3} & \displaystyle\frac{1}{2}
\end{array}\right)\begin{bmatrix}g(a)\\g(\frac{a+b}{2})\\g(b)\end{bmatrix}.$$

This formula is invariant under integration by parts, i.e., the right-hand side exactly reproduces

$$\int_a^b f(t)dg(t)+\int_a^b g(t)df(t)=f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a),$$

and reduces to Simpson's rule if $\,g(t)=t\,$ is a linear function. I derived this myself but would appreciate anyone who can find me a reference.

Comment: Huh, so formatting DOES work. Anyway, using your method i get
$$\frac{73.33-44}{6}\left(1.2+4(1.7)+2.3\right)=50.3498$$
$$\frac{102.66-73.33}{6}\left(2.3+4(3)+3.9\right)=88.9677$$
$$\frac{132-102.66}{6}\left(3.9+4(4.8)+5.9\right)=141.81$$
$$\frac{161.33-132}{6}\left(5.9+4(7.1)+8.5\right)=209.221$$
and the answer is 490.348 (after doing conversions, that's what my numbers are a bit off)

The only problem I have is that your midpoint comment isn't completelyright, 1.7 is not between 1.2 and 2.3, same with 7.1 being between 5.9 and 8.5. I don't know if this will effect the problem tho.

Comment: Both methods should get you $564.67\,\mbox{mph}\cdot\mbox{sec}=828.18\,\mbox{ft}$. You have done the $\int tdv$ integral and the integration by parts would get you $\int vdt$.