# A generalized Simpson's rule

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

In solving [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2507996/simsons-rule-but-intervals-arent-the-same), I developed a generalized Simpson's rule

$$\int_a^bf(t)dg(t)=\begin{bmatrix}f(a),\;f(\frac{a+b}{2}),\;f(b)\end{bmatrix}\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
\displaystyle-\frac{1}{2} & \displaystyle\frac{2}{3} & \displaystyle-\frac{1}{6}\\\displaystyle-\frac{2}{3} & 0\, & \displaystyle\frac{2}{3}\\
\displaystyle\frac{1}{6} & \displaystyle-\frac{2}{3} & \displaystyle\frac{1}{2}
\end{array}\right)\begin{bmatrix}g(a)\\g(\frac{a+b}{2})\\g(b)\end{bmatrix}+\mathcal{O}(|a-b|^5).$$

assuming $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are sufficiently differentiable. This formula is exact for $f(t)=t^m$ and $g(t)=t^n$ with $m+n\leq 4$, where $m,n$ are nonnegative integers. The formula is invariant under integration by parts, i.e., it exactly reproduces

$$\int_a^bf(t)dg(t)+\int_a^bg(t)df(t)=f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a).$$

In case $g(t)=t$ is linear, the method reduces to the standard [Simpson's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule). Is this formula seen in the literature? Please show me a reference.

Comment: I googled many sources but could not find this one. It puts the smooth functions $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ on equal footing, so the integrand of $\int fdg$ need not be sampled on equally spaced grids of $g$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is a special case of a big class of *differential operators* called 'Summation-by-Parts' (SBP) operators. They are defined as follows:

A matrix $D$ is an SBP operator of order $s$ if $D$ can be decomposed as $D = P^{-1}Q$ such that the following properties hold:

1) $D\mathbf{x}^m = m\mathbf{x}^{m-1}, \quad m=0, 1, \dots, q$,

2) $P = P^\top > 0$,

3) $Q + Q^\top = B = \text{diag}(-1, 0, \dots, 0, 1)$.

For two vectors $\mathbf{f}$ and $\mathbf{g}$, we may define the discrete inner product $(\mathbf{f},\mathbf{g})_P = \mathbf{f}^\top P \mathbf{g}$. Then, since $D \mathbf{g} \approx \mathbf{g}_x$, the identity
$$
(\mathbf{f},D \mathbf{g})_P = \mathbf{f}^\top Q \mathbf{g} = \mathbf{f}^\top (B-Q^\top) \mathbf{g} = f_n g_n-f_0g_0 - \mathbf{f}^\top Q^\top \mathbf{g} = f_n g_n-f_0g_0 - (D\mathbf{f},\mathbf{g})_P
$$
is the discrete version of the integration by parts rule
$$
(f,g_x) = \int_a^b fg_x dx = f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a) - \int_a^b f_xgdx = f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a) - (f_x,g),
$$
as you noted.

While SBP methods can be constructed for almost any type of differential operators (finite difference, finite volume, finite element etc.), the particular one you have derived originates within the context of spectral collocation methods. Let $P_n(x)$ be the Legendre polynomial of order $n$. Further, let $(x_0, \dots, x_n)$ be the roots of $P'_n(x)(1-x^2)$ (i.e. the Legendre-Gauss-Lobatto nodes) and let $L_j(x), j=0, \dots, n$ be the Lagrange interpolation polynomials associated with these points. Then $P$ is the diagonal matrix whose non-zero elements are given by
$$
P_{j,j} = \int_{-1}^1 L_j(x) dx
$$
and the elements of $D$ are given by
$$
D_{i,j} = L'_j(x_i).
$$
The matrix you have derived (with $n=2$) is $Q$ and is simply given by $PD$, or explicitly
$$
Q_{i,j} = \int_{-1}^1 L_i(x) L'_j(x) dx.
$$
Of course, the method may be generalised to any $n \geq 1$.

For a detailed study of these methods, see Carpenter and Gottlieb (1995), *Spectral methods on arbitrary grids*.

Comment: Yes, when there are multiple intervals, it becomes clear that the integration formula is some sort of bilinear product between $f(t)$ and the differencing of $g(t)$ at intervals of $|a-b|/2$.

Comment: Indeed. Note that we don't have to use the Legendre-Gauss-Lobatto nodes for this to work, however the accuracy of the integral is the quoted one with these nodes (and in general a bit lower on an arbitrary grid).

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't really understand the "Legendre-Gauss-Lobatto nodes" argument. The local error is $5$-th order because we can Taylor expand $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ around $(a+b)/2$ and then all $t^mdt^n$ Taylor terms with $m+n\leq 4$ are integrated exactly.

Comment: It's just a minor detail, but the quadrature rule associated with the SBP operator (i.e. the matrix P) is of different order depending on how the grid points/nodes are distributed. The LGL nodes gives you a few bonus orders. With $n=2$ they happen to be the equidistant nodes that you have used but if you increase $n$ this might change.

Comment: I see. The reason why Simpson's $3/8$-rule has no bonus is because the LGL nodes for $n=3$ are no longer equidistant. Thanks!